# Button in tabBarItem without viewController?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, tabbar

How to add one extra button on TabBar without a view controller because i want to handling that button click form following method ...

```
override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem)
    {
        if (tabBar.items?.firstIndex(of: item))! == 3{
         //button click do some thing on existing view 
        }
    }
```

i already add three buttons with ViewControllers with following code

```
 let VC = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: 
 Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(identifier: VCidentifier)                                                 
 VC.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: selectedImage)
 VC.tabBarItem.selectedImage = UIImage(named: unSelectedImage)
```

and then add these ViewControllers to this

```
viewControllers = [firstVC,secoundVC,thirdVC,fourthVC]
```

but i want to add forth button without a view controller ...

Comment: From the docs: "Tab bar items are configured through their corresponding view controller. To associate a tab bar item with a view controller, create a new instance of the UITabBarItem class, configure it appropriately for the view controller, and assign it to the view controller’s tabBarItem property. If you don't provide a custom tab bar item for your view controller, the view controller creates a default item containing no image and the text from the view controller’s title property."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to add tab bar button without view controller. But you can create empty view controller and use [UITabBarControllerDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbarcontrollerdelegate?language=objc) to make whatever you want when the fourth button clicked.

Comment: Oh man ... it means i have to do some extra work for that ... i am trying to do it by this method and stuck in another problem .. any way i posted another question regard same problem ... please answer that with some example code ...  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60787371/how-to-open-side-menu-from-tabbar